# Need help in understanding the below plot generated using randomForestExplainer library in R

Tags: r, random-forest

[image]

I am not able to understand what this plot depicts and what we mean by the relation between rankings.Let me add a few more things to make it a bit precise. This plot is generated by using plot_importance_rankings function available as part of randomForestExplainer package.

A sample code which generates this code is as

```
plot_importance_rankings(var_importance_frame)
```

where var_importance_frame contains important variables which we get as from

```
var_importance_frame <- measure_importance(rf_model)
```

Here rf_model is the trained random forest model. A sample example can be found at this [link](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/randomForestExplainer/vignettes/randomForestExplainer.html)